# How to check if database changes exist - Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Let's say I have been coding for a couple days and can't remember if I made any changes to the database. What I currently do is go to the package manager console and "add-migration" and see if any changes exist. If none, then I delete my migration. If I do have changes then I still delete my migration and re-add the migration with a better migration name that reflects the actual change.

Is there anything with Entity Framework Core that will inform me that changes exist or something that will tell me the changes that exist without actually creating a migration file and updating the snapshotContext?

I know I could look through the change logs of my db entities but it becomes a hassle when I have several commits.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: @MaxP - No I did not